# Don't display time if midnight using Moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How do I use http://momentjs.com/docs/ to only display the time if it is not midnight?  For instance, please look at the first example below.

```
console.log(moment('2016-01-28 00:00:00').format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss A'));
// Desire 01/28/2016, Get 01/28/2016 12:00:00 AM

console.log(moment('2016-01-28 05:03:50').format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss A'));
// Works correctly.  Desire 01/28/2016 5:03:50 AM, Get 01/28/2016 5:03:50 AM
```

A possible non-elegant solution would be to use JavaScript to check if the datetime trails with 00:00:00, and if so, provide a format string of 'MM/DD/YYYY' instead of 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss A', but I expect there is a more proper way to do so.

Comment: var time = moment().format("Hms") != "000" ? moment().format("what format you want") : ""

Comment: @Vanojx1  Pleases see my edited post.  Looks like I should use your recommendation of `moment().format("Hms") == "000" `, and then just use a different format.  Right?  Thanks

Comment: "what format you want" means the final format that you need for your date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways.  Here's one way (concise enough for most purposes):

```
var dt = moment('2016-01-28 00:00:00');
console.log(dt.hours() === 0 && dt.minutes() === 0 && dt.seconds()=== 0 ? dt.format('MM/DD/YYYY'): 
       dt.format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss A'));
```

Comment: Ended up just using `function myMoment(t){return t?(t.substring(11)=='00:00:00'?moment(t).format('MM/DD/YYYY'):moment(t).format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss A')):'';}`.  Didn't know if moment had some sort of backed in option.  Thanks

Comment: My recommended way would work if the input string is '2016-01-28' so it's not as 'fragile' as yours.

Comment: Thanks.  I agree, and that is why I chose your solution as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

If milliseconds are a concern, you can use `isSame()` and `startOf()`:

```
const dt = moment('2020-10-31 00:00:00');
console.log(dt.format('MM/DD/YYYY' + (dt.isSame(moment(dt).startOf('date')) ? '' : ' h:mm:ss A')));
```